# How to detect and remove CSV columns based on common text in header names?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am working on a CSV File which I recently created. The CSV file contains columns with headers and corresponding rows.

I need to remove entire columns (including its data) that have specific text common to their headers. For e.g column 1 has header named `intID`, column 2 has header named `boolID`, column 3 has header named `charID` and so on ('ID' being the common text). There are some columns that don't have 'ID' as text in their headers, so we need to retain those.

The csv file is getting generated dynamically, so there may be more/less columns based on what data we select for the csv. But we need these columns with their headers having some common text to be removed.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Do you already have some code to share?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like that do the trick?

```
$yourfile = "<path to your csv>"
# Import the CSV
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $yourfile
# Find all columns that do not end with "ID"
$colsToKeep = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |?{$_.name -notmatch "^.+ID$"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
# Filter out all unwanted columns
$newCsv = $csv | Select-Object -Property $colsToKeep
# Export CSV to new file
$newCsv | Export-Csv -Path "<path to new csv>"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. it worked perfectly. however i am having another issue. the CSV file is the output of a SQL Stored Procedure. ( i generated the CSV via a SQL job step using the command -- sqlcmd -S localhost -d DBNAME -E -W -w 1024 -s"," -Q "EXEC SQLSP" -o "CSV(ESCAPE_NONE(DATE)).csv". The actual csv containing client data contains about 30-40 columns and i noticed that the columns are getting displayed in multiple rows, rather than on the first row itself. The data of the columns are displayed fine Any idea how to get all the column headers on the top row (Row 1)

Comment: Hey I was able to figure out the issue that i was facing.However on a Win 2008 R2 server Inotice that the line $newCsv = $csv | Select-Object -Property $colsToKeep gives an error Select-Object : Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At line:1 char:31+ $newCsv = $csv | Select-Object <<<<  -Property $colsToKeep+ CategoryInfo :InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand. Thoughts?

Comment: Hm apart from that, is the rest of the code identical? This looks suspiciously like the error that would happen if `-expandProperty` was missing from the previous line :p

Comment: Hey, i got a query, I generated a CSV with UTF8 encoding, since i needed , as data in certain columns. The CSV was good, and then i proceeded to remove those columns. with the script that you gave. However on $newCsv = $csv | Select-Object -Property $colsToKeep it gives me an error Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}. Is it to do with the UTF8 encoded csv. How can i remove those columns keeping the encoding intact.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

- the ID part is not a plain text "ID" but a dynamic arbitrary text
- headers of interest start with `int`, `char`, `bool`

Let's count occurrences of ID part and build a list of headers used just once, then export the CSV.

```
$csv = Import-Csv 1.csv

$prefix = '^(int|char|bool)' # or '^([a-z])' for any lowercase text
$headers = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name
$uniqueIDs = $headers -creplace $prefix, '' | group | ? Count -eq 1 | select -expand Name
$uniqueHeaders = $headers | ?{ $_ -creplace $prefix, '' -in $uniqueIDs }

$csv | select $uniqueHeaders | Export-Csv 2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note: in the old PowerShell 2.0 instead of `? Count -eq 1` use `?{ $_.Count -eq 1 }`

Comment: the ID is plain text.  For e.g. below are the column headers that are part of my CSV file.  As you can see there are many headers with text  ID appended at the end. So we need to remove these, rest we need to keep. Action ProcRskMatSrchId ProcId ProcTabId OrgUnitId OrgUnitTabId ProcRskTabId ProcCntrlTabId CntrlName CntrlOwner OrgUnitName OrgUnitParent ProcCntrlId ProcName ProcParentName ProcRskId ProcRskMatId RskName RskSignif RskSignifCatValID RskTyp RskTypCatValID

Comment: This info should have been in the question, it always makes answering easier. Well, use the other answers.